# Warning: mysql_fetch_array

Tags: mysql, arrays, warnings, fetch

I get following Error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in......

Here is my query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user' AND password = '$pass'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $expire = time()+60*60*24*30;
                setcookie("id", $row['id'], $expire);
                echo "Logged in. as <b>.".$row['username']."</b>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are missing a ' on the left side of $user in this (I have added it here):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'");
```